# find + grep to match exact keywords in a file

Tags: grep, find

My script is not matching exact words only. Example: `12312312Alachua21321` or `Alachuas` would match for `Alachua`.

```
KEYWORDS=("Alachua" "Gainesville" "Hawthorne")
IFS=$'\n'
find . -size +1c -type f ! -exec grep -qF "${KEYWORDS[*]}" {} \; -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `grep` to match exact words, use `grep -w`.

You may also want to read the `grep` manual by running `man grep`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to resolve my issue and I'll be sure to read over the manual.